# How to change shape type in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I can see that Slides have `getShapeType` but don't have `setShapeType` method.

How may we udpate the shape type in Google Slides?

This is possible from the Google Slides context menu, but does not appear to be possible using Google App Script.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean make custom shape?

Answer (score 0):

From [Class Layout](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout) you can use getShapes to goto [Class Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape.html) where there are a lot methods for working with shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot change the type of an existing Shape with Apps Script. This is not possible even with Slides API (you can change the shape properties in [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate), but this doesn't include the shape type).

Once a Shape is created, the type is set, and if you want to have a Shape that has another type, you have to create a new one.

There are ways to achieve this, though, even if not so direct and fast:

#### Workaround #1 (Apps Script methods):

Using Apps Script built-in methods, you could do the following:

- Get the properties of the shape you want to update (including position, rotation, scaling, color, etc.), with the corresponding methods (`getRotation`, `getHeight`, etc.).
- Delete this existing shape via [Shape.remove](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape.html#remove).
- Create a new shape with the same properties as the old one, but with a different shape, via [Slide.insertShape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertshapeshapetype).

See for example, this sample, in which the position, rotation and dimensions of an existing shape is retrieved, then the shape is removed, and finally a new one is created with the same position, rotation and dimensions of the old one, and a triangular shape:

```js
var left = shape.getLeft();
var top = shape.getTop();
var rotation = shape.getRotation();
var height = shape.getHeight();
var width = shape.getWidth();
shape.remove();
var shapeType = SlidesApp.ShapeType.TRIANGLE;
var newShape = slide.insertShape(shapeType, left, top, width, height);
newShape.setRotation(rotation);
```

#### Workaround #2 (Advanced Slides Service):

You could also activate [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides) and use Slides API to accomplish the same process. You would have to do the following:

- Retrieve the shape properties via [presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)
- Remove the old shape via [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate), providing a [DeleteObjectRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#DeleteObjectRequest).
- Create a new shape with the properties of the old one and the new shape type via [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate), providing a [CreateShapeRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#CreateShapeRequest).

#### Note:

I'd suggest you consider filing a Feature Request in [this Issue Tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191598#basic) explaining the potential usefulness of this desired functionality.

#### Reference:

- [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest)
- [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides)
- [Slide.insertShape(shapeType, left, top, width, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertshapeshapetype,-left,-top,-width,-height)